# Override Playframework Routes

Tags: java, playframework-1.x

We use Play 1.2.x with Java and the application supports more than one client. We would like to override play framework routes to have more than one routes file and forward request to corresponding controller method based on client ID.

For Ex, the main routes will have all routes

```
/home   HomeController.loadHomePage
/create CreateController.create
```

we want to have client specific file like this

```
/home   CustomHomeController.loadHomePage
/create CustomCreateController.create
```

When request comes for particular client it should check client specific routes file and forward the request

Is it possible to achieve in Play framework

Comment: Couldn't you do this kind of thing from within the controller? (Only learning play at the moment, but that was an idea I had - direct all traffic through a central controller and allow it to control the route...)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is always NO.

You MUST implement redirect within controller by yourself, and it will be redirect to difference controller if matching some your conditions.

Reason:

- Play!1.x implement routes by create static hashmap, and no change in runtime.
- When server starts, it load all routes to static hashmap, and when navigate to an url, routes will find controller in the hashmap.